# Web Crawler using c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, web-crawler

I'm planning on crawling a website using **c++**. I have gathered information on how to crawl a website from base. I download the webpages using **winhttp** library. I want to build one of my own and not use third party libraries. The information I gathered are :

1.Check **robots.txt** to find which page can be crawled and find the request time gap.

2.Check if the site has **sitemap.xml** and gathering information from it.

3.Check all the **href** or url tags and find the folders in it.

Is there anything else that I should do inorder to crawl a website fully?

Answer (score 1):

You should add database support. I would recommend using [Sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html). 
You should have a mechanism for storing the current state of the crawler so if case of premature termination, it can continue from where it stopped last time.
Using winhttp library can carry several limitations:
- HTTPS support will be a bit limited. For example, support up to 128-bit (see [SSL in WinHTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/ssl-in-winhttp)).
- Margin cases of invalid / expired SSL certificate which can be overridden by a browser user. Also HTTP site with a HTTPS prefix and vice versa.
I would use [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) and [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) instead of winhttp.